# Postgres text [ ] wild card search

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, full-text-search

I need to build this query with JPA criteriaBuilder.

```
SELECT *
FROM row
WHERE value = ANY (String[])
```

Is this possible?

I tried to make a custom function like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_in(col_name text[], search_value 
VARCHAR)
RETURNS BOOLEAN AS $sql$
DECLARE
   sql_part TEXT;
BEGIN
sql_part = concat('(',search_value,' ANY (' , col_name , ')) ');


RETURN sql_part;
END;
$sql$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

search_in(myCol, Bob) would return ''bob' = ANY (myCol)'.
This is the postgresql syntax to search inside a ArrayType

But this does not work as it return a string injected in the query and it wil not be executed/evaluated? Is there a way to do this?

Leave String[] behind and making a table for it and join this table would solve it was it not that it would kill the performance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution but its not exactly fast, still looking for a beter one!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_in(values text[], search_value VARCHAR, )
RETURNS boolean as $sql$
DECLARE
  bit_val boolean;
BEGIN
  SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS
(select *
from context_data
where
      search_value = ANY(values))
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT)
ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT) into bit_val END;


  RETURN bit_val;
END;
$sql$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```